# Use multiple @Where for single collection using JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose we have 3 entities (Regular annotations skipped):

```
class User {
    public List<Task> tasks;
    ...
}

class Task {
    public Result result;
    ...
}

class Result {
    ...
}
```

And now, I want to have another collection on User for getting lists of tasks which has result (result is not null) but I don't want to have different collection(column) in database, I just want to have filtered version of tasks (like running query on it), so it I add the task to tasks, I don't need to add it to tasksWithResult again. Example:

```
class User {
    public List<Task> tasks;
    /**
    * Get filtered version of the tasks
    * Add something here like @Where, @Filter or something like them
    */
    public List<Task> tasksWithResult;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can refer here for filters - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html

Comment: Did you find a solution?